# Einstein equation outside of the source

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, vacuum

When solving Einstein equation outside the source it is assumed that we have $R=0$ where $R$ is Ricci tensor. But if we have as a source Earth and for example, a black hole, how can this equation account for that if it neglects T (energy momentum tensor)? I would expect curvature arround a black hole to be different than that around Earth. I do not see from this equation how can we have this?

Comment: As with every equation, not only do you have to solve it but you also have to define boundary conditions. If you only solve for the outside of a spherically symmetric spacetime, you get a variety of Schwarzschild solutions which can solve the vacuum Einstein field equations. You'll need to define some conditions on the boundaries (for instance continuity with some interior solution) to select a specific mass of Schwarzschild

Comment: Yes! Of course....thank you! How did I forget this? I guess I got lost, reading this stuff...and cant think any more...tnx again.

Comment: @Slereah I feel like your comment should be an answer.